# Symfony and star rating : how use input jquery and symfony2 together

Tags: jquery, symfony

I use symfony2 and i want to use a star rating widget...

I also use jquery...

Anyone know CAN  how we do?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: There are tons of tutorials out there that go over this feature in detail. Stack Overflow is more of a place for specific questions. Try building the feature yourself, and if you're stuck with something specific, post here and we'll be more likely to help.

Comment: This question is far too vague to be of use to people. We need more detail on what specifically you're having issues with.  As @Arms said, if you get stuck, post back with the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include js files in your twigs. In < HEAD> part use this (this will go into web/Resources):

```
{% javascripts 
    'Resources/public/js/jquery/jquery.min.js'
    'Resources/public/js/jquery/plugins/yourplugin.js'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And then you can run your jquery plugins (also in twig file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.className').pluginName();
    });            
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Tanks for Your response. But I Want to know if you know how CAN I

Comment: Add class to a specific field?

Comment: not sure what do you mean. Are you asking how to implement star rating plugin on the page?